# Cakephp:Capturing Digitized Signature using signature pad eg Topaz

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

has anyone attempted to create a MySql/Cakephp solution to capture and archive digital signatures using topaz pads/tablets?

Will http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/ help me to get signature capture from touch pad devices? I have Topaz T-LBK462-HSB-R, any suggestions, links, idea how do I go about it, I am stuck guys on this task, any help.

Comment: I believe [here](http://thomasjbradley.ca/articles/saving-signatures-php-mysql/) is all you need for it. He's also using MVC architecture, so just adapt it to cake. All about saving, DB structure and drawing the stored signature is in his example...